# How to handle multiple file upload in hunchentoot?

Tags: web, lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I know how to handle a single file upload in hunchentoot using `hunchentoot:post-parameter`, but when I add a property `multiple`, i.e., `<input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>`. I got `(hunchentoot:post-parameter "file")` only for one of them. Is there (and what is ) the mechanism for receiving all files, chosen by user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hunchentoot API does not directly give you access to multiple uploaded files, but you can use `(hunchentoot:post-parameters *request*)` to retrieve the list of all POST parameters (which includes the uploaded files).  This will be an alist, and you can get a list of all uploaded files using standard alist techniques (e.g. `(remove "file" (hunchentoot:post-parameters hunchentoot:*request*) :test (complement #'equal) :key #'car)`).

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather straight-forward task in hunchentoot. Assuming you have a html `<input>` element with `name="files"` and `multi="true"`, you could access all the files associated with the the "files" input like this:

```
(loop for post-parameter in (hunchentoot:post-parameters*)
            if (equal (car post-parameter) "files")
            collect post-parameter))
```

This will give you a list whose length should match the number of uploaded files associated with the name "files". Each of the elements will be a list that looks like this:

```
("files" #P"/temporary/file1" "name of file" "file type")
```

More information can be found in the very well-documented [reference](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/#reference).